# React Leaflet NextJS - interactive bug map (unsynchronized images)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, leaflet

I have a small problem, I use leaflet react, but I have this kind of rendering

[image]

The first zoom is perfect in itself (complete image, but weird contour), but as soon as I switch to Zoom 1, 2, 3..., I get this bug.

[image]

Here is my code, and thanks to the person who will solve my problem (Components)

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet"

import { api } from "@/lib/trpc/react"

type Props = {
  mapSlug: string
  mapBase: string
}
export default function MapGenerator({ mapSlug, mapBase }: Props) {
  const dataMap = api.maps.data.useQuery({ mapSlug, mapBase })
  const mapContainerStyle = {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    zIndex: 1,
  }
  return (
    <div className="mt-4 h-full w-full overflow-visible">
      <div className="flex h-[90%] w-full flex-col gap-4 rounded-medium border-small border-divider">
        <MapContainer
          center={[0, 0]}
          zoom={0}
          scrollWheelZoom={true}
          style={mapContainerStyle}
          attributionControl={true}
        >
          <TileLayer
            url={dataMap.data?.mapUrl ?? ""}
            maxZoom={dataMap.data?.maxZoom}
            minZoom={dataMap.data?.minZoom}
            tileSize={256}
            noWrap={true}
          />
          <Marker position={[0, 0]}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Other information:

- The map doesn't do fullscreen, it has to follow my main div that delimits it. This is the only thing.

PS: I test for 100vh height, but, this problem is not solved